# Change server IP Add-on

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Is there any Add-On for Firefox or Chrome that enable modifying the server IP address without changing the hosts file? 
for the host specified in the URL address bar, the browser will skip DNS resolving and instead will take it from the Add-On input.
is it possible to create something like this?

Comment: As this could very easily be abused, I would guess that this is not possible.

Comment: this can be very helpful, for example, if you want to test a new server with new code without changing the hosts file. or if you have more than one servers behind a load balancer and want to see which one is serving wrong content, if you need to send host header to a server that does not have DNS record.  I don't see why you think that it can be abused.